# Logout from second activity

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

In my app, users login using facebook. When user clicks on button in first activity, facebook dialog opens for username and password. User provides details in this dialog. After successful login, user moves to second activity where user can see his personal details such as name, email id, location etc. Now, for the logout from the app, I have put logout option in menu. Below is my code.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      private static List<String> permissions;
        Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        String id, username, email, birthday, location, gender;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button fbButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

            /***** FB Permissions *****/

            permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            permissions.add("email");
            permissions.add("basic_info");
            permissions.add("user_about_me");
            permissions.add("user_birthday");
            permissions.add("user_location");
            permissions.add("user_notes");
            permissions.add("user_status");

            /***** End FB Permissions *****/

            fbButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Check if there is any Active Session, otherwise Open New Session
                    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

                    if(!session.isOpened()) {

                        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(MainActivity.this).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(permissions));

                    } else {
                        Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true, statusCallback);
                    }
                }
            });

            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if(session == null) {
                if(savedInstanceState != null) {
                    session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
                }
                if(session == null) {
                    session = new Session(this);
                }
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
                session.addCallback(statusCallback);
                if(session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(permissions));
                } 
            }
        }


        private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                //Check if Session is Opened or not
                processSessionStatus(session, state, exception);
            }

        }

        public void processSessionStatus(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

            if(session != null && session.isOpened()) {

                if(session.getPermissions().contains("email")) {
                    //Show Progress Dialog 
                    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    dialog.setMessage("User is Logged in..");
                    dialog.show();
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {


                            if (dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            if(user != null) {
                                Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                                responseMap = graphObject.asMap();
                                Log.i("FbLogin", "Response Map KeySet - " + responseMap.keySet());
                                // TODO : Get Email responseMap.get("email"); 

                                //String fb_id = user.getId();
                                //String email = null;
                                //String name = (String) responseMap.get("name");
                                if (responseMap.get("email")!=null) {
                                    email = responseMap.get("email").toString();
                                    id = user.getId();
                                    birthday = user.getBirthday();
                                    username = user.getName();
                                    location = (String) user.getLocation().getProperty("name");
                                    gender = (String) user.getProperty("gender");
                                    Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Second.class);
                                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                                    extras.putString("ID",id);
                                    extras.putString("Email", email);
                                    extras.putString("Birthday", birthday);
                                    extras.putString("Username", username);
                                    extras.putString("Location", location);
                                    extras.putString("Gender", gender);
                                    in.putExtras(extras);
                                    startActivity(in);
                                    MainActivity.this.finish();

                                }
                                else {
                                    //Clear all session info & ask user to login again
                                    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                                    if(session != null) {
                                        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    session.requestNewReadPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(MainActivity.this, permissions));
                }

            }
        }

        /********** Activity Methods **********/

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Log.d("FbLogin", "Result Code is - " + resultCode +"");
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(MainActivity.this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            // TODO Save current session
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            Session.saveSession(session, outState);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            // TODO Add status callback
            super.onStart();
            Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Remove callback
            super.onStop();
            Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() 
        {
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }


    }
```

### Second.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.logout:
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            Intent in = new Intent(Second.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            super.finish();

        }
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I click on Logout option, I am moving to first activity, but when I click on Login button again in first activity, my app force closes. What needs to be done to logout appropriately?

Comment: what your logcat shows

Comment: @Ye :java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session...

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code -

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.logout:
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            Intent in = new Intent(Second.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            super.finish();

        }
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: session = Session.getActiveSession(); In this line i am getting null ,so in my second activity there is no session how to create session which is created in first activity